# Inverse of (i*I+A) for self adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

If we have that $A: H \rightarrow H$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, then the spectrum of $A$ is entirely real, i.e. $\sigma(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  Hence we know that $i$ is in the resolvent set of $A$, and in particular $(iI+A)^{-1}$ exists where $I$ is the identity.  Is there any way to find $(iI+A)^{-1}$ explicitly?  I tried to write it in terms of a geometric series (something like $-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty (iA)^n$) like we did for showing the resolvent set is open, but that obviously won't converge unless $\|A\| < 1$.  Is there any other way that the inverse can be solved for explicitly?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "explicit". Think of the operation of multiplication by $x$. You can approximate $(i+x)^{-1}$ uniformly by polynomials on a finite interval, but not uniformly on the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this:
$$
    (iI+A)^{-1}  = -i(I-iA)^{-1} = -i\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t(I-iA)}dt
    = -i\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}e^{itA}dt
$$
You can expand $e^{itA}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}i^nt^nA^n$ integrate using the Gamma function:
$$
     \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{-1+\alpha}dt,\;\;\Re\alpha > 0.
$$